# Apache mod_jk and virtual hosts

Tags: virtualhost, apache, mod-jk

I have configured apache with mod_jk, to redirect the `/taste` context to my application server. Now I would like to create a virtual host, so that my domain name redirects to this context.

I tried the following configuration in httpd.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.suitmytaste.com
    ServerAlias suitmytaste.com *.suitmytaste.com
    DocumentRoot /taste
</VirtualHost>
```

But apache does not accept the /taste part as a DocumentRoot. How can I configure it so it redirects the virtual host to the mod_jk connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by removing the `DocumentRoot` line, and adding the following lines instead :

```
JkMount / worker1
JkMount /* worker1
```

with `worker1` being the worker I had configured in mod_jk `worker.properties` file.

Comment: How did you configure that your content lies in /taste ?

Comment: The content is not static so it does not lie in any particular folder. It is instead genrated by tomcat dynamically. The purpose of mod jk is to act as a proxy between apache and tomcat, so it delegates the request to tomcat instead of serving a static file.